# How can i hide the remove button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filepond

i added FilePond to my laravel / vue 3 project .

i want to hide the remove button i added `allowRemove=false` but it did not work.

my code:

```
<file-pond
    name="image"
    ref="pond"
    allowRemove=false
    class-name="my-pond"
    label-idle="Drop Images here..."
    allow-multiple="true"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    allowDrop=true
    :server="'/api/upload/'+productId"
  />
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on where exactly the `file-pond` element comes from? I assume it's [`pqina/vue-filepond`](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond)?

Comment: I think it should be `allow-remove="false"` as well as `allow-drop="true"`

Comment: @MattU i tried that too, but remove button still get shown

Comment: Can you possibly create a minimal reproducible example on Stackblitz and share the link here?

Comment: i dont think it is possible cuz i have to install filepond trough npm

Comment: @MattU i upload on a git repo : https://github.com/SimodevStuff/shopify-add-product-clone/blob/spa/resources/js/components/AddProduct.vue#L19

Comment: see this forked codesandbox from official GitHub repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filepond-live-demo-forked-d5u4h?file=/src/components/FilePondDemo.vue . both `allowRemove="false"` and `allow-remove="false"` works fine. you could use it to create a reproducible example, it has the package installed already.

Comment: @IgorMoraru
@MattU i see know why know ...
the problem is that `allowRemove` is responsible to remove the remove button that get shown on the item wish is just dropped server propriety as you see on the image: https://ibb.co/GRyksdj 

the remove button i want to delete is that wish it get shown after the upload is complete wish has the server proprity. as you see on the image: https://ibb.co/5LMSdpP

Comment: and i dont think it possible to remove it.

Comment: @Forbidenn you should read the server configuration page: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/ . There are some endpoints created by default, including the ‘revert’ endpoint. By disabling it, I think the button will be removed or deactivated at least.

Comment: @IgorMoraru `allowRevert="false"` did the job thanks for your time . edit it with some code so i can accept it as an answer .